# Regular Expression in ASP.NET for alpahnumeric characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I cannot manage to get a working regular expression (for use in ASP.NET Validataor) for the following criteria:

- I want all chars from A-Z a-z 0-9
- I don't want the Enter key

I have the expression: `[\w\s,.-/]*[^\n]` but that doesn't work.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Your regex example allows spaces, commas, dots, hyphens and slashes. Those doesn't belong to "all chars from A-Z a-z 0-9". You really, *really*, REALLY need to be more precise and descriptive.

Comment: By "I don't want the Enter key", do you mean "I want to match the parts of the string that don't contain \n" or "I don't want to find any matches if the string contains \n"?

Comment: some help : [Regular expression basics](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/help/regularexpressionbasics.htm)

Answer (score 3):

This will match only characters that you're requiring:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Comment: Hi... I forgot to told that i need the space char too.
If i use your expression with the space [A-Za-z0-9\s]+ the enter is allowed too :(

Comment: @TiagoDias: `\s` is all white space characters, if you only want space " ", then include it directly `[0-9 a-zA-Z]+`.